# Editing /etc/hosts to use domain name instead of ip address

Tags: linux, hosts-file

I have a web service running at `http://192.168.1.2:5000/`, I want to replace it with a typical domain name,

in /etc/hosts, I'm doing something like

```
192.168.1.2:500 http://www.mydomainname.com
```

but, its not working. Anything wrong with how I did it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, /etc/hosts associates IP addresses with hostnames

So, there are two things wrong with your line:

- 192.168.1.2:500 is an IP address and a port
- http://www.mydomainname.com is an URI and not a hostname

So, the line should be

```
192.168.1.2 www.mydomainname.com
```

You then access via http://www.mydomainname.com:500 from your browser of choice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

- 192.168.1.2:500 is not an IP address.  It is an IP address *plus a port*.
- http://www.mydomainname.com is not a domain name.  It is a URL, *part of which* is a domain name.

`/etc/hosts` maps IP addresses to hostnames, and vice versa.  It is not a URL rewriting tool for WWW browsers.  With it, one can map the name `www.example.com` to the IP address 192.168.1.2, and *that's it*.  No ports, schemata, paths or anything else enter into the matter.